# Adding whitespace to web page source so that I can read it

Tags: whitespace, html-parsing, readability

1. I'm curious about the web page I'm viewing.
2. I use the "view--page source" and get a window with the html.
3. I cut and paste this into notepad++.
4. I manually parse through adding whitespace to make it readable to me.

Is there a better way to do the last step? I'm hoping something has been written which automates this process, giving the user a readable version of the source file.

Thanks for any help.

-bill

Answer (score 4):

Try [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Numerous editors have support for HTML Tidy (if you use an editor that knows about HTML, check the menus or documentation); alternatively, you can run HTML Tidy from the command line.

Comment: Thanks so very much. This is very helpful. I'm running from the command line for now. So much easier to read in multiple sensible lines. Eventually I'll set some parameters to get nested tags indented.

Answer (score 2):

There is HtmlTidy, which works in Notepad++

http://tidy.sourceforge.net

Comment: Does it work as a plug in? I don't see it in my plugin manager, but maybe I need to change some settings. I see a HTML tag. Are there any other plugins which are particularly helpful for html editing for notepad++? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, it has been a long time and I'm editing with Vim now, so I can't confirm. That is the only HTML formatting tool for n++ of which I know anything.